# Making the height/width of.a UICollectionViewCell dependent of the screen size

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have three `CollectionViews` in a single `ViewController`. If I now set the constraints, the amount of cells per column changes and that ruins my application. Is there a special way - without constraints - to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement

```
let scW = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let scH = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

  if collectionView == col1 {
      return CGSize(width:<##>,height:<##>) // supply ratio of screen width/height
  }
  else ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: And what am I supposed to do afterwards? Setting constraints again?

Comment: this will over write constraints so no need for them anyway

Comment: Ah great I see it. Now the width is okay. The height does not really change even tough I increase it in your code